# Hypothetically, how long would it take to circumnavigate New Zealand by foot?

Tags: factoids, hiking, new-zealand, walking

This would include looping around the three major islands - the North Island, the South Island, and Stewart Island.

Some calculation or reference would be useful, rather than a stab in the dark, which is what I'm currently doing with some paper and a lack of sleep.

Comment: One does not simply ... walk around New Zealand.

Comment: There's also the Te Arora Trail: http://www.teararoa.org.nz/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

my name is Brando Yelavich. I'm 19 and I'm simply walking around New Zealand without using roads, so on the beaches and coastlines living off the land. You can watch my progress here http://wildboy.co.nz (facebook page).

I'm 78 days in and just about at the bottom of the north island. It is going to take me about 1 1/2 years. I'm doing it solo, so no support crew, just me and my pack. Just the mapping took 3 weeks, to do it depends on the type of person you are to whether you could take this adventure on.

Comment: Lucky for you, Travel.SE doesn't have Wikipedia's "no original research" clause!

Answer (score 3):

Using Google maps, I did a rough estimate for walking around the South Island.  The estimate comes to 2894 km.  According to Google, this would take 24 days and 23 hours.  I don't think the Google estimate includes any time for sleeping and eating, so assuming you walk 12 hours a day you'd have to double that.

Comment: that's one of the three islands, but at least it's the biggest.  25 days. Assuming 7-8 hours a day actual walking, that's 3 months.

Comment: All the good walks come to about 3 months for some reason. I once worked out walking the length of Japan and another time from the northernmost tip of Finland to Poland, and both came to pretty much three month. (Haven't done either trip yet though.)